# Rails scope test for nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a worequest model and it belongs_to employee.

I would like to have a worequest scope that shows the employee_id = nil

I thought this should work:

```
    scope :notassigned, where(:employee_id => nil)
```

But, I get the error:

```
undefined method `notassigned' for nil:NilClass
```

This is the view code:

```
    <% @worequests.notassigned.each do |worequest| %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
undefined method `notassigned' for nil:NilClass
```

This means the object on which you call the method `notassigned` is `nil`

So, in your case, the variable `@worequests` is `nil`.

```
<% @worequests.notassigned.each do |worequest| %>
   ^
   # This is the nil that raised the error
```

Comment: My bad - I forgot to add the controller code to get the records - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are calling your scope on an empty instance variable, hence the `undefined method for nil:NilClass`.  When you create a scope, it is really just creating a class method so you must run it on respective class, not an instance of that class.

Try running your query like this:

**Controller**

```
@worequests = WoreQuest.notassigned
```

**View**

```
<% @worequests.each do |worequest| %>
```